# Customer registration error after Magento migration

Tags: magento, migration, magento2

After Migration from Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.3.4 when I go to create a customer and fill all the information and click on submit(on front-end), it show me error

```
We can't save the customer.
```

After debugging I found the error below:

```
Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime does not exist
```

I tried to search the class on the database and also in files, with no results. However, I found something similar in the table `eav_attribute`:

```
Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post, [“We can't save the customer” error after Migration - Magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263636/we-cant-save-the-customer-error-after-migration-magento-2-3), I did the following:

1. I searched for `Datetime` values in `eav_attribute.frontend_input`.
2. I found several Mailchimp records with this value.
3. After I changed the `Datetime` values to anything else (`Date`, `Text`, …), it works again.

Answer (score 0):

edit attribute 'mailchimp_sync_delta' frontend_input datetime to date worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).